# how to make a meteor template helper re-run/render after another template has rendered?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a template helper called {{renderNav}} in a template Nav

e.g.

```
Template.Nav.renderNav
```

and within that helper function I want to parse the rendered output of another helper within a different template

For example the helper

```
Template.contentWindow.content
```

which provides the html for

```
{{content}}
```

and my renderNav helper wants to part the html that replaces {{content}} to generate the     html for

```
{{renderNav}}
```

how would I do this? right now the {{renderNav}} helper executes for or runs more quickly and so it is unable to parse the html that replaces {{content}}

@Hugo - I did the following in my code as you suggested

```
Template.contentWindow.rendered = function() {
    debugger;  
    return Session.set('entryRendered', true);
};

Template.Nav.renderNav = function() {
    debugger;
    var forceDependency;
    return forceDependency = Session.get('entryRendered');
};
```

When I run it, the debugger first stops when executing the renderNav helper. (Which makes sense with what I am seeing in terms of the race condition). Then contentWindow renders and I hit the breakpoint above the Session.set('entryRendered', true). But then the renderNav doesn't run again as you suggest it should. Did I misinterpret or incorrectly implement your suggestion?

Comment: Not sure what your are trying to do. Suppose `content` ends before `renderNav`. How do you access `content` html from within `renderNav`?

Comment: I am trying to access the html that the content helper renders from within the renderNav helper. Which is causing a sort of race condition where renderNav executes first and is not able to access the DOM HTML that the content helper puts out.

Comment: Although you can hack it, it sounds like you're doing something the wrong way. Why do you need the DOM of an template you rendered yourself? You should have all the data you need in `renderNav` context. Maybe you could add some `renderNav` code to explain how it uses `content` DOM segment.

Comment: you are probably correct that I'm not doing it a very meteoric way... a code fragment would not be very descriptive in this case but the explanation is... the {{content}} helper renders as a page with any number of headings in it (H1,H2,H3,etc...); the renderNav helper is part of a sidebar template that parses the content for those headings and effectively builds a table of contents --- so i don't know how I would pass the html that the content helper produces to the renderNav helper

Comment: See the update to my answer. Does it help?

Comment: The meteoric way to do it would be to rely on the raw data and not on the rendered result. In `content` you use some logic to generate the headers text. Make this logic a function and use it in `content` as well as in `renderNav`. Just make sure to use the same context in both.

Comment: @HubertOG I am at work now but I will try it when I get home, it makes a lot of sense so It hink it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a dependency in the template that you want to rerun. There are few possibilities, depending on what data you want to get.

For example, you can set a reactive marker in the `content` template that will notify `renderNav` that it's done with drawing.

```
Template.contentWidnow.rendered = function() {
    ...

    // Set this on the very end of rendered callback.
    Session.set('contentWindowRenderMark', '' +
        new Date().getTime() +
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) );
}


Template.renderNav.contentData = function() {
    // You don't have to actually use the mark value,
    // but you need to obtain it so that the dependency
    // is registered for this helper.
    var mark = Session.get('contentWindowRenderMark');

    // Get the data you need and prepare for displaying
    ...
}
```

---

With further information you've provided, we can create such code:

**content.js**

```
Content = {};
Content._dep = new Deps.Dependency;
```

**contentWindow.js**

```
Template.contentWidnow.rendered = function() {
    Content.headers = this.findAll(':header');
    Content._dep.changed();
}
```

**renderNav.js**

```
Template.renderNav.contentData = function() {
    Content._dep.depend();
    // use Content.headers here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hugo, I see what you are suggesting but it does not seem to work. I made an edit to my question above to show you what I tried based on your suggestion.

Comment: Setting `true` shouldn't work. Because it doesn't change the value except the first time. Use `Random` or even better `Deps.Dependency`

Comment: Yes, in my example I use `Date()` and even add some `random()` to make sure the value is changed.



Custom `Deps.Dependency` is another valid way to do this, even better (lower level) than `Session` - provided that you have a good way to share the dependency between template files.

Comment: last question I promise! I implemented this but now am getting the console exception: Exception from Deps recompute: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Comment: this happens outside of any code that I directly run, it is caused by the context being null within Spark when it is trying to computePreservations

Comment: It's hard to tell for me without seeing more of your code. It looks like you get a null inside the headers table somehow, or you do something with the headers that leads to a variable in jQuery chain being null.

Comment: Btw, it's Hubert, not Hugo :)

Comment: The null error is because of the way that the page currently renders within Meteor, your page may render more than once before the data context is ready, so you will probably have null the first time there is a render, and another when the publish function is done rendering.  I know this is post is older, but FYI

Answer (score 3):

If you want the navigation to be automatically rebuilt when contentWindow renders, as Hubert OG suggested, you can also use a cleaner, lower level way of invalidating contexts:

```
var navDep = new Deps.Dependency;

Template.contentWindow.rendered = function() {
    ...
    navDep.changed();
}

Template.renderNav.contentData = function() {
    navDep.depend();

    // Get the data you need and prepare for displaying
    ...
}
```

See http://docs.meteor.com/#deps for more info.

If, on the other hand, you want to render another template manually, you can call it as a function:

```
var html = Template.contentWindow();
```

The returned html will not be reactive. If you need reactivity, use:

```
var reactiveFragment = Meteor.render(Template.contentWindow);
```

See the screencasts at http://www.eventedmind.com/ on Spark and reactivity for details on how this works.

**UPDATE**

To add a rendered fragment to your DOM:

```
document.body.appendChild(Meteor.render(function () {
    return '<h1>hello</h1><b>hello world</b>';
}));
```

You can also access the rendered nodes directly using the DOM API:

```
console.log(reactiveFragment.childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: I do think this is correct but not working for me, so I'll keep digging... With the Deps.Dependency method the contentData helper executes first as expected, then the contentWindow.rendered executes calling navDep.changed(), which in turns triggers the contentData helper to run again (which is exactly what I want!), unfortunately while the contentData helper appears to return the correct html, nothing is rendered to the DOM and neither of the helpers are executed again (where before I was getting stuff rendered to the DOM it was just the previous pages content instead of the current pages)

Comment: Are you are using reactiveFragment inside renderNav? Then you are creating a dependency loop, where contentWindow depends on renderNav and renderNav depends on contentWindow.

Comment: No I just inserted the navDep code you showed in the first half of your post while keeping everything else the same. Its not entirely clear to me how I would use the reactiveFragment code in this situation. Is the idea that I would call Meteor.render(Template.contentWindow); from within the renderNav helper and then do my Nav parsing on that returned html rather than on the DOM html?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain reactiveFragments in more details.