# Meteor, Facebook comments load only if the page was reloaded

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use Facebook comments (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments). The problem is they only load when a page is refreshed, so if I come from any other route I get nothing loaded. I make the call in template.rendered, which is properly executed when I arrive at the page, both when refreshed and from another route. What may be causing this behaviour? I tried to debug this, but there's nothing I can see, nothing I've tried worked. Cheers.

PS: As requested in the comments - Fb function is a generic one, wrapped up like this:

```
function loadFbComments() {
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=694645587257406&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
}
```

I call it in Template.rendered:

```
Template.item.rendered = function(){
loadFbComments();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Router:

```
Router.route('/item/:_id', function () {
  this.render('Item', {
      path: '/:permalink',
    data: function(){
        var permalinkVar = this.params.permalink;
        return Items.findOne({permalink: permalinkVar});
      },
    });
});
```

This is really just the standard code, I guess the issue is to do with Iron Router, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Share some code maybe?

Comment: Added relevant code to the post

Comment: Nothing seems off to me here, but if you think it's iron-router maybe try standard way to define it, yours is deprecated https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md

Comment: I've updated the code with suggested way, but that didn't help. My guess is purely based on deducing from the behaviour. The code does work after all when browser is refreshed. There must be a trigger somewhere in the Facebook function that is connected to standard javascript document.ready or similar. I will try to init the comments when the app loads first and show them only on post page, maybe this will solve the issue (although, I'm not crazy about this solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up loading entire comments section into another template that then is loaded once in layout template (my main template). I use the comments in a modal anyway, so it's hidden by default. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the template that contains fb comments.

You can do this using [tracker dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#tracker_dependency) or updating a session variable for example.

[how to make a meteor template helper re-run/render after another template has rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584522/how-to-make-a-meteor-template-helper-re-run-render-after-another-template-has-re)