# Dynamic subscription with Date range Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to dynamically subscribe to a collection filtering them by date.

My server code looks like this

```js
Meteor.publish('caja', function(skip, desde, hasta) {
  if (desde && hasta === 'NA') {
    return Cajas.find({}, {
      skip: skip,
      limit: 25,
      sort: {
        fecha: 1
      }
    });
  } else if (hasta === 'NA') {
    return Cajas.find({
      fecha: {
        $gte: new Date(desde)
      }
    }, {
      skip: skip,
      limit: 25,
      sort: {
        fecha: 1
      }
    });
  } else {
    return Cajas.find({
      fecha: {
        $gte: new Date(desde),
        $lte: new Date(hasta)
      }
    }, {
      skip: skip,
      limit: 25,
      sort: {
        fecha: 1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

My client code looks like this

```js
var desdeVar, hastaVar, skipVar;
skipVar = new ReactiveVar(0);
desdeVar = new ReactiveVar('NA');
hastaVar = new ReactiveVar('NA');

Template.caja.onCreated(function() {
  var self;
  self = this;
  return self.autorun(function() {
    var desde, hasta, skip;
    skip = skipVar.get();
    desde = desdeVar.get();
    hasta = hastaVar.get();
    return self.subscribe('caja', skip, desde, hasta);
  });
});

Template.caja.events({
  'change #hasta': function(e, t) {
    var hasta;
    hasta = new Date($('#hasta').val());
    return hastaVar.set(hasta);
  },
  'change #desde': function(e, t) {
    var desde;
    desde = new Date($('#desde').val());
    desdeVar.set(desde);
    return console.log(desdeVar.get());
  }
});
```

So when I change the date I want to dynamically subscribe to the date range established in the client.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just curious! can you please check whether you are getting subscribed data on UI by simple using {{#each}}. If you  are not getting any data, the issue is with subcription at "onCreated()".

Comment: I am, actually there is a table below that throws the subscribed data, but when I try to filter out by dates, the data still remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check that your template is re-running when a property value changes (e.g.  your date value).  If your changing an html input value which isn't being tracked and wouldn't force your template/query to rerun (unless you're saving the field value in a reactive var, etc of a template helper function) , you'll need catch the event and invalidate the template to force a re-render.   See below where you can setup deps.changed() to trigger;

[how to make a meteor template helper re-run/render after another template has rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584522/how-to-make-a-meteor-template-helper-re-run-render-after-another-template-has-re)

Comment: The subscription works with String and Number values, but not Dates. The Dates Are the problem

Comment: $and?   Cajas.find({ $and: [{
      fecha: {$gte: new Date(desde)} , fetcha: {$lte: new Date(hasta)} 
     ] }

Comment: or possibly if fetcha is a date/time and filtering on same day, may need to set time of hasta to T23:59:59

Answer (score 0):

I solved it after checking 2 dumb mistakes Ive made.

```js
Meteor.publish('caja', function(skip, desde, hasta) {
  if (desde == 'NA' & hasta == 'NA') {
    return Cajas.find({}, {
      skip: skip,
      limit: 25,
      sort: {
        fecha: 1
      }
    });
  } else if (hasta === 'NA') {
    return Cajas.find({
      fecha: {
        $gte: new Date(desde)
      }
    }, {
      skip: skip,
      limit: 25,
      sort: {
        fecha: 1
      }
    });
  } else {
    return Cajas.find({
      fecha: {
        $gte: new Date(desde),
        $lte: new Date(hasta)
      }
    }, {
      skip: skip,
      limit: 25,
      sort: {
        fecha: 1
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Where desde and hasta had to be seperately equal tu 'NA',

Second I used only the new Date() in the server instead of the client and the server.

Sorry for the inconvenience